Experience Site Article - URL Name Isn't Working
In a sandbox (which may be the root of my problems, but unfortunately I only have sandbox access) I am trying to add an aura component to the article detail page, which includes a recordId attribute.
Where I am running into an issue is that when I use the prescribed url formatting for a test knowledge article (e.g. article/urlName) I get a page does not exist error. If I hard code the article ID into the article (e.g. article/recordId) then it works just fine.
I have also tried appending the article type in the url as recommended as a solution in some other posts here (e..g article/how_to/urlName) but that has not worked.
